# React Serverside rendering Unexpected token, JSX and Babel

Tags: babeljs, react-router, reactjs

I'm having trouble finding the correct way to use babel to allow me to use jsx in serverside.

Node-jsx was deprecated for babel.  It seems like `babel-core/register` is whats supposed to be used but I still get unexpected token issues.

I created a repo with the problem im having.

https://github.com/pk1m/Stackoverflow-helpme

When I run `node app` or `npm run watch-js` I keep getting unexpected token referring to the JSX code '<'.

How do I get babel to transpile JSX, or am I completely off, thanks.

Comment: You haven't installed babel-loader. Check this project out for sample config files. https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use `babel-register` (`npm i babel-register --save`). And run on your server:

```
require('babel-register')({
    stage: 0
});
```

You can omit stage 0 if you aren't using experimental babel features. Also you might prefer to put those options in `.babelrc` instead.

Note that it will only work for files required AFTER calling that (so it would not have an effect on the file you include it in).

You could also have the presets and other options in a `.babelrc` file.

For **babel 6x**:

```
npm i babel-register babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react --save

require('babel-register')({
    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
});
```

Note: there are also stage 0-2 presets.

For watching as you've written in your package.json you could try a CLI command like the one facebook are suggesting in the note [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#productionizing-precompiled-jsx) (or use webpack):

```
babel --presets react es2015 --watch app/ --out-dir build/
```

Comment: ok, I'll try that when I get home.  Is JSX an experimental babel feature?

Comment: @pk1m no jsx and other es6 features will work, stage 0 is for proposed things like `static` in es7, and other experimental stuff (static is nice if you're using React.Component instead of React.createClass)

Comment: ok, I used `require('babel/register')` but it says it was deprecated for `require('babel-core/register')`.  So I used that instead if you can see in my git.  Still throws errors for '<'

Comment: @pk1m are you using babel 5 or 6? 6 is different

Comment: I'll use whichever one that I can get to work.  In my example app its babel-core v6

Comment: @pk1m personally I'm having trouble getting 6 to work for everything, it was released a few days ago and not everything is working smoothly yet. For me though it's es7 features I am having trouble with so I'll update the post

Comment: this looks super promising because I've tinkered around with different packages and i could only get es6 OR jsx to work.  Never both. Ill update when i get home to try it.  thank you!

Comment: Note that `babel/register, babel-core/register` are now deprecated in favor of `babel-register`.